# How do I sort a Set to a List in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

In Java, I have a `Set`, and I want to turn it into a sorted `List`.  Is there a method in the `java.util.Collections` package that will do this for me?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The answer [provided by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740299/how-do-i-sort-a-set-in-java/740301#740301) is not the best. It is inefficient, as it creates a new `List` *and* an unnecessary new array. Also, it raises "unchecked" warnings because of the type safety issues around generic arrays.

Instead, use something like this:

```
public static
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c) {
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(c);
  java.util.Collections.sort(list);
  return list;
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
/* Add entries to the map. */
...
/* Now get a sorted list of the *values* in the map. */
Collection<String> unsorted = map.values();
List<String> sorted = Util.asSortedList(unsorted);
```

Comment: @erickson where I have to find Util class, I mean  from which package.Please help me.

Comment: @sunleo The `Util` class is the one that contains the `asSortedList()` method I wrote. In other words, you write the `Util` class yourself, and put that code in it.

Comment: ha ha I thought its from default pack like java.util ok thank you.

Comment: This might be a nice generic Utility function, but the fact is, it is still not efficient. Consider in-place sorting by making sure you have your set in the right container to begin with. Also consider usage of the TreeSet as a direct container of your data. If your data needs to be unique anyhow, and you need a Set, then use the TreeSet, catches two flies in one swat.

Comment: As a note to the people only reading the top answer: Have a look at nschum's answer below, which uses Java 8's streams. If you can use Java 8, go for it. they are more flexible and efficient.

Comment: @Felk While it's definitely nicer to read and more efficient *to write,* the `Stream`-based example below is a bit slower—about 10% slower in my tests. Of course, if performance is that important, using the right collection in the first place is the best solution.

Answer (score 84):

Sorted set:

```
return new TreeSet(setIWantSorted);
```

or:

```
return new ArrayList(new TreeSet(setIWantSorted));
```

Comment: This was my first thought, but the asker wanted a List

Comment: @Alex: This approach can still be used; return new ArrayList(new TreeSet(setIWantSorted))

Comment: I actually used this solution, but I wouldn't advise this. As the documentation on TreeSet states (see http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), it effectively uses the compareTo() method instead of the equals() method - so if you have two objects in the set that have the same equals() outcome, they will be seen as duplicates and, as such, will not be added to the TreeSet. Beware.

Comment: @fwielstra: How can you have objects that are equal in the input since the input is also a `Set` ?

Comment: @ryanprayogo It's worth mentioning, as `new TreeSet` accepts `Collection`s, not just `Set`s. Not everyone who is reading this answer is going to be using a `Set`, even though that's what the original question is asking.

Answer (score 57):

Here's how you can do it with Java 8's Streams:

```
mySet.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or with a custom comparator:

```
mySet.stream().sorted(myComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Best. Best. Best.

Answer (score 46):

```
List myList = new ArrayList(collection);
Collections.sort(myList);
```

… should do the trick however. Add flavour with Generics where applicable.

Comment: I had a useful snippet I wanted to donate to the community.  When I searched for the information, I couldn't find it.  I was trying to make the next person's job easier.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-unofficial-faq#119658

Comment: Yeah, sure, but that link you provided is actually talking about a _real_ questions (i.e. those for which don't have the answer, then find it). Your question here was only to give the answer... I could actually enter hundreds of questions and answer myself; that's not the point!

Comment: @Seb: I disagree. I don't see anything wrong with this question. It obviously wasn't an extremely simple question, and now he knows a better way than he did before!

Comment: It *was* a real question, but I found the answer myself after Google came up short.  Stackoverflow didn't exist at the time.  I had it posted on my website and it helped someone else, so I thought it might be useful here.

Comment: Bonus: And if you happen to be sorting your own object type then you can always implement `Comparable` and override `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 10):

Always safe to use either Comparator or Comparable interface to provide sorting implementation (if the object is not a String or Wrapper classes for primitive data types) . 
As an example for a comparator implementation to sort employees based on name

```
    List<Employees> empList = new LinkedList<Employees>(EmpSet);

    class EmployeeComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

            public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
                return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
            }

        }

   Collections.sort(empList , new EmployeeComparator ());
```

Comparator is useful when you need to have different sorting algorithm on same object (Say emp name, emp salary, etc). Single mode sorting can be implemented by using Comparable interface in to the required object.

Answer (score 5):

There's no single method to do that.  Use this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Comparable> List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> collection) {
  T[] array = collection.toArray(
    (T[])new Comparable[collection.size()]);
  Arrays.sort(array);
  return Arrays.asList(array);
}
```

Comment: There is also a Collections.sort function, but I think it does the same thing. +1 anyways.

Comment: Collections.sort takes a list as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a set into an `ArrayList`, where you can sort the `ArrayList` using `Collections.sort(List)`.

Here is the code:

```
keySet = (Set) map.keySet();
ArrayList list = new ArrayList(keySet);     
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TreeSet sortedset = new TreeSet();
sortedset.addAll(originalset);

list.addAll(sortedset);
```

where originalset = unsorted set and list = the list to be returned

Comment: TreeSet also de-dupes the list which can result in the wrong outcome if you don't assume that.

Answer (score 3):

@Jeremy Stein I wanted to implement same code. As well I wanted to sort the set to list, So instead of using Set I converted set values into List and sort that list by it's one the variable.
This code helped me,

```
set.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(ModelClassName::sortingVariableName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code, which I find more practical than the accepted answer above:

```
List<Thing> thingList = new ArrayList<>(thingSet);
thingList.sort((thing1, thing2) -> thing1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(thing2.getName()));
```