# How do i convert a set to a sorted array using java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

HashMultimap return a set of values for a given key.how do i convert this java set to a sorted array? Is there a way other than converting it into a sorted list using java.util.collections.sort(....) and then using a to array?

Comment: should be same question as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740299/how-do-i-sort-a-set-to-a-list-in-java

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the sort implementations?

Comment: If you don't need an array specifically, but rather just want the Set's elements to be sorted, consider using a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashSet`.

Comment: no i need it as an array.too many casts if i used a list in between

Comment: Too many casts? What are you doing with this array?

Answer (score 4):

Two lines:

```
Object[] array = set.toArray();
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

TreeSet implements SortedSet. Construct a new TreeSet with the values obtained from the multimap.

```
HashMultimap<K,V> hm = new HashMultimap<>();

// (...) alter hm

TreeSet<V> ts = new TreeSet<>(hm.values());
//or
TreeSet<V> ts = new TreeSet<>(hm.get("key"));

V[] ordered = (V[]) ts.toArray();
```

I don't know exactly how efficient the ordered insertion is, so I don't know if this is a good solution. Look for a detailed comparison in the Java documentation.

For reference: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

Comment: The very link you posted describes the efficiency: `This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains).`

Comment: If i am creating a new treeset it is a lot of memory if my V is a big data structure..and how do i convert treeset to an array