# Java HashMap iteration to find driving end event

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I'm working on a project where I have to determine when a driving event ends. A function is given an `HashMap<Date, Integer>` containing confidence levels of in vehicle/on foot in form of a percentage alongside a unix timestamp.

I'm attempting to iterate over this HashMap, determine if a driving event has ended.

I'm a PHP developer, and its a real challenge using Java logic like this, and I'm struggling to achieve something that should be simple. Any help appreciated.

Heres the logic I'm trying to implement:

```
If 
  we have at least 1 minute worth of data with 10 items in our HashMap 
then
  loop HashMap
     if past 30 seconds of time, from 30 seconds ago contain driving data of 60% confidence adverage or above then
     AND past 30 seconds of time from now contains working data with average 60% confidence or above
     then 
        mark isDriving as true
if isDriving == true 
then
   doSomething()`
```

My HashMap looks something like this:

```
private HashMap mActivityData = new HashMap<String, Long>();

mActivityData.putExtra("in_vehicle",80); // % confidence
mActivityData.putExtra("on_foot",10); // % confidence
mActivityData.putExtra("time",1461684458); // unix time stamp
```

Comment: Get your generics right, e.g. for the data shown: `private HashMap<String, Long> mActivityData = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Actually, a Map doesn't look correct here, if the values are different types (% vs timestamp). Assuming you don't need to dynamically create new keys, just use three properly-typed variables: `double in_vehicle; double on_foot; Date time;`.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What have you tried and where does it fail?

Comment: [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) doesn't seem to have a putExtra() method . . . only put() and putAll()

Comment: It seems like a `hashmap` in its true since is not the best solution here. Your map represents more of an object relational model. Why not create a class called `Activity` that holds variables for the confidences and the time stamp. If you need multiple ones per activity, this can be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a partial answer.

You have mentioned "loop HashMap { ... } " in your question, but you can only loop over the keys of the hashmap. (or over the values with `.values()`)

To get the keys of a `HashMap<Date, Integer>`:

```
Set<Date> dates_unordered = my_hashmap.keySet ();
```

A Set is unordered, to order it use a function like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/740351/) to create an ordered list. (the "Date" class implements the "Comparable" interface which is needed for that sorting to work)

```
List<Date> dates_ordered = asSortedList (dates_unordered);
```

Iterate over the list.

```
Iterator<Date> it = dates_ordered.iterator (); // create an iterator object
while (it.hasNext ())
{
  Date d = it.next ();
  Integer i = my_hashmap.get (d); // access value in hashmap with this key

  // do something with "i" here
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That's great, solved my problem. Thanks for the great explanation.